# How to set datasource of listbox from generic list of class

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I bind List to the datasource of a Listbox? I want to to set the visible property Name.

Here is my class and list:

```
 public class Users
 {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Data { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Users()
    {
        Name = null;
        Data = DateTime.Now;
        Id = 0;
    }
    public Users(string N,DateTime dateTime, int id)
    {
        Name = N;
        Data = dateTime;
        Id = id;
    }
}
```

Here is how I try to bound the datasource:

```
        ListBox1.DataSource = ((List<Users>) Application["Users_On"]);
        ListBox1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  ListBox1.DataSource = ((List<Users>) Application["Users_On"]);
  ListBox1.DataTextField = "Name";
  ListBox1.DataBind();
```

You can use the [DataTextField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.datatextfield) property of the ListBox class to display the Name propperty of your object.

Comment: have you checked the content of your list if has data? debug and set break point

Comment: Okay i forgot about list.add to add my user to list thx for help:)

Answer (score 0):

Alex, not really sure how you are trying to generate and bound the values, I'll try to simplify, lets say I have a class called `GenericLists`, where I'll declare all the reusable generic data, let's assume products for example so I can do like this :

```
private Dictionary<int, string> relatedProducts { set; get;}
public Dictionary<int, string> relatedProductsList { 
        get {return relatedProducts; } 
    }

public GenericLists()
{
        relatedProducts = new Dictionary<int, string>
            {
                    {0, "CTRL + Click to select multiples"},
                    {1, "A"},
                    {2, "B"},
                    {3, "C"},
                    {4, "D"},
             };
}
```

And now I want to bind it to a listbox in any form :

```
  GenericLists gList = new GenericLists();

            products.DataSource = gList.relatedProductsList;
            products.DataValueField = "Key";
            products.DataTextField = "Value";
            products.DataBind();
```

I hope this would give you an idea.

Good Luck